# R very slow on macOS Sierra

Tags: r, runtime-error, macos-sierra

I'm on macbook pro, with macOS Sierra. Since i changes OS, moving from Maverick, R (3.4.0) stops working properly.
It is very slow and I get a lot of these messages on the console

```
2017-05-26 20:38:06.603 R[11341:1100511] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (1.76 secs).
2017-05-26 20:38:48.405 R[11341:1100511] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (1.47 secs).
2017-05-26 20:38:53.096 R[11341:1100511] *** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteView informAuxServiceOfSelf], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-282/NSRemoteView.m:3209
2017-05-26 20:38:53.101 R[11341:1100511] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : [self textInputContext]=0x6000000abac0 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=com.apple.ViewBridge Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.apple.ViewBridge.error.hint=__38-[NSRemoteView _advanceToConfigPhase:]_block_invoke.2462 caught NSInternalInconsistencyException '<NSRemoteView: 0x600000324ec0> failed to rendezvous via aux service' with backtrace (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff995fc37b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffae3f048d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99601082 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9b048ce0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface46c60 -[NSRemoteView informAuxServiceOfSelf] + 345
    5   ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface475aa -[NSRemoteView _finishAdvanceToConfigPhaseWithContextID:andServiceViewSize:andOffset:] + 685
    6   ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface5b3c4 __38-[NSRemoteView _advanceToConfigPhase:]_block_invoke.2462 + 103
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9956fc3c __invoking___ + 140
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9956fac1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 289
    9   ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface826a9 withHintInProgress + 487
    10  ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface823e0 __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 + 233
    11  ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface06779 +[NSViewServiceApplication withHostPID:invoke:] + 46
    12  ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface822a3 __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke + 179
    13  ViewBridge                          0x00007ffface81e97 __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 + 544
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9959221c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99573034 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff995727b5 __CFRunLoopRun + 917
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff995721c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98ad3ebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
    19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98ad3bf9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184
    20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98ad3b26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9706ee24 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff977ea85e -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
    23  R                                   0x0000000106665b01 -[RController doProcessEvents:] + 385
    24  R                                   0x00000001066694ac Re_ProcessEvents + 188
    25  libR.dylib                          0x000000010693d9ae R_ProcessEvents + 46
    26  libR.dylib                          0x000000010681154d R_CheckUserInterrupt + 77
    27  libR.dylib                          0x0000000106817504 Rf_eval + 68
    28  libR.dylib                          0x0000000106825fac Rf_evalList + 108
    29  libR.dylib                          0x00000001068671dc do_internal + 172
    30  libR.dylib                          0x000000010681bde8 bcEval + 16520
    31  libR.dylib                          0x0000000106817701 Rf_eval + 577
    32  libR.dylib                          0x0000000106827e52 R_execClosure + 898
    33  libR.dylib                          0x000000010681bd04 bcEval + 16292
    34  libR.dylib                          0x000000010682991e R_compileAndExecute + 718
    35  libR.dylib                          0x0000000106828c7d do_for + 173
    36  libR.dylib                          0x000000010681786c Rf_eval + 940
    37  libR.dylib                          0x000000010685852e R_ReplDLLdo1 + 446
    38  R                                   0x0000000106677ddf run_REngineRmainloop + 287
    39  R                                   0x000000010666be31 -[REngine runREPL] + 225
    40  R                                   0x000000010665aba1 main + 817
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffaecd5235 start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
), com.apple.ViewBridge.error.description=NSViewBridgeExceptionError}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
```

It seems that running R from the terminal there are no problems. Any help?

Comment: I get same error. please do update if you ever figured this out.

Comment: I start using Rstudio (which i hate) and It seems to work better